# h:outputLink prefixes context path to a URL value

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2

I have a `h:outputLink` as shown below:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{doc.value}" style="color:blue">#{doc.key}</h:outputLink>
```

The value is a URL www.example.com. When I click on the value, the URL I am seeing in the address bar is `http://localhost:8080/Project/www.example.com`. Why is the context path being prefixed to the URL?

I looked up the HTML generated, but the value is the actual URL without the context path. I tried `<a>` in the JSF, but there's no difference.

Any help to fix this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<h:outputLink />` **appends its value to the current parent path (not the Servlet Context) if the value field is a relative path**. It means that if you have this specific link in `http://localhost:8080/Project/users.xhtml`:

```
<h:outputLink value="sales.xhtml">
    Sales
</h:outputLink>
```

This will try to redirect you to `http://localhost:8080/Project/sales.xhtml`.

Well, as you're specifying a relative one, JSF understands it must append it to your current parent url. In order to avoid that, write the absolute url:

```
public String getValue(){
    return "http://www.example.com";
}
```

```xhtml
<h:outputLink value="#{doc.value}">
    Custom external url
</h:outputLink>
```