# Clicking on Links in JSF failing

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, javabeans, uirepeat

I am trying to display a URL as a result in my UI after some processing. So far I have used

```
URL: 
<h:outputLink value= "#{entry.value}"><h:outputText>"#{entry.value}"
</h:outputText></h:outputLink>
```

When I click on a link that is displayed the URL in the browser is of the form localhost:8080/ProjectName/URL

But I want the page to be displayed when I click the URL on the UI. Any help would be great.

Comment: Does that URL belong to your application or it's an external one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699352/houtputlink-prefixes-context-path-to-a-url-value/22706380#22706380

Comment: Thanks for the answer...If you can post this as an answer it would be great..